# $O(1)$ algorithm for coin change w/out nickels

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

For the coin changing problem in the case without nickels (only quarters, dimes, and pennies available), assuming you use quarters until $x < 50$  since it's better to use quarters for $x \geq 50$; $x$ is the change) what would be an $O(1)$ algorithm that, given an input $n$, returns the number of quarters, dimes, and pennies that give the correct change with a minimum amount of coins??

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your model of computation, you might not even be able to read the input in time $O(1)$.  But assuming all the standard arithmetic operations can be done in unit time, which seems to be the case here, the number of quarters (call it $q$) is
either $\lfloor n/25 \rfloor$ or $\lfloor n/25 \rfloor + 1$.  You then have
$n_1 = n - 25 q$ cents to make up with dimes and pennies, and you use
$\lfloor n_1/10 \rfloor $ dimes ...

Comment: So continuing the same logic, after using $n_1/10$ dimes I would have $n_2 = n_1 - 10c$. Would the pennies be $n_2/1$ pennies or $n_2 = 1$?

Comment: I'm thinking of this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
The following is pseudocode that does what you ask:

getCoins(remainder){
    if(remainder >= 30){
        // 30 <= remainder < 36 || 40 <= remainder < 46
        if(remainder % dime < 6){
            coins += remainder/dime 
            coins += remainder % dime
        // 36 <= remainder < 39 || 46 <= remainder < 49
        } else {//remainder % dime >=6      
            coins += remainder/quarter  
            coins += remainder % quarter
        }
        return coins
    // 25 <= remainder < 29             
    } else if(remainder >= 25){
        coins += remainder/quarter  
        coins += remainder % quarter
        return coins
    // remainder < 25 
    } else {
        coins += remainder/dime
        coins += remainder          
        return coins
    }
```

}

```
/* This is the function that, given an amount, will return the minimum number of coins that can change the amount into quarters, dimes and pennies. 

change(amount) {
quarter = 25
dime = 10
pennie = 1
coins = 0
/*First we check if the starting amount is greater than 50*/ 
if(amount >=50){
    //If amount=a*50+b, "multiple_of_50" will be a*50 //always.
    multiple_of_50 = amount-amount%50
    //And here we get b into the variable "remainder"
    //for later use
    remainder = amount % 50
    //Here we add the number of quarters in a*50 to coins.
    coins += multiple_of_50/quarter;
    /*
    Now, because of what we did above, remainder is less than 50 always.                
    */
    coins += getCoins(remainder)
} else {//amount < 50
    coins += getCoins(amount)
}
return coins
```

}